# How can I expose the dynamic $PORT from Heroku in a Dockerfile?

Tags: heroku, docker, dockerfile

How can I expose the dynamic $PORT from Heroku in a Dockerfile?
I push my docker container with `heroku container:push web --app=...` to Heroku, this works.

In there Heroku logs however I read this:  `heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`, I interpret this as if the port from my Dockerfile can't be exposed through Heroku.

No documentation can be found about this. How can I expose my Docker port to the Heroku port?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

ADD binary_file .

EXPOSE 37780

CMD ["./binary_file"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can (isn't the port dynamic?).

I think you are supposed to use the `PORT` environment variable in your app (ie, your app has to bind to that port inside the container).

Supposing your app would start the python http server, your CMD should be something like this:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/python -m SimpleHTTPServer ${PORT}"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however in my specific case I don't have the opportunity to define a port for the binary running inside the container.

Comment: What about having another service redirect the port inside your container (ie, that service binds to the random heroku port, and redirects all the traffic to your app fixed port)?

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a legit solution, and way to easy for me to forget. Thanks @Salem!

Comment: If you need something to do that, you can try `rinetd`. Good luck

Comment: Did you end up going with `rinetd`? Having the same problem.